# AWS KMS, Create CMK with SDK for Java

Tags: java, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I'm starting to work with the AWS SDK for Java, specifically to make use of the KMS service.

The first thing I need to do is creating a CMK key so I'm following the examples on the developer guide provided by the official documentation.

```
AWSKMS kmsClient = AWSKMSClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration).build();

String desc = "Key for protecting critical data";
CreateKeyRequest req = new CreateKeyRequest().withDescription(desc);
CreateKeyResult keyResult = kmsClient.createKey(req);
```

However if a run the application for trying to create the CMK key, I get the following error which I don't know how to solve.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body><h1>Host Not Found</h1>
<p>DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist) or Server did not accept the connection.<br><br>Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.<br></p>
<!--Zscaler/5.7--></body></html>
"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2630)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4042)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2571)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonContent.parseJsonContent(JsonContent.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonContent.<init>(JsonContent.java:64)
    at com.amazonaws.protocol.json.JsonContent.createJsonContent(JsonContent.java:54)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:61)
    at com.amazonaws.http.JsonErrorResponseHandler.handle(JsonErrorResponseHandler.java:33)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handleAse(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:53)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:41)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AwsErrorResponseHandler.handle(AwsErrorResponseHandler.java:26)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1642)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.doInvoke(AWSKMSClient.java:3506)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:3475)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:3464)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.executeDescribeKey(AWSKMSClient.java:1126)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.describeKey(AWSKMSClient.java:1097)
    at com.thalesgroup.aws.kms.KmsServiceTest.getCMKInformation(KmsServiceTest.java:51)
    at com.thalesgroup.aws.kms.KmsServiceTest.main(KmsServiceTest.java:16)
17:38:32.994 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.AWSKMSException: null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.kms.model.AWSKMSException: null (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1660)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1324)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1074)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.doInvoke(AWSKMSClient.java:3506)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:3475)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.invoke(AWSKMSClient.java:3464)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.executeDescribeKey(AWSKMSClient.java:1126)
    at com.amazonaws.services.kms.AWSKMSClient.describeKey(AWSKMSClient.java:1097)
    at com.thalesgroup.aws.kms.KmsServiceTest.getCMKInformation(KmsServiceTest.java:51)
    at com.thalesgroup.aws.kms.KmsServiceTest.main(KmsServiceTest.java:16)
```

It seems to be like two errors, one is a JsonParseException and in other hand a 404 error code is printed as part of the response that can not be parsed.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (byte[])"<html><head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body><h1>Host Not Found</h1>
<p>DNS error (the host name of the page you are looking for does not exist) or Server did not accept the connection.<br><br>Please check that the host name has been spelled correctly.<br></p>
<!--Zscaler/5.7--></body></html>
```

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check what's in your `clientConfiguration`. It looks like you're using proxy and it doesn't allow/know how to connect to AWS KMS endpoint.

Comment: I set up a proxy via the ClientConfiguration object for connecting to S3 service using the SDK and it worked well. So, it's the same configuration I'm trying to use for KMS.